# remove rm command not working with wildcards on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I am trying to remove the below file for all user accounts through a bash script but the wildcard * does not seem to work. I have been testing the script locally by running it on mac os x terminal.

Plist file to be deleted: com.apple.eap.bindings.XXXXXXX.plist

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in /Users/*;
do
    if [[ -e "${dir}/Library/Preferences/com.apple.eap.bindings.*" ]]; then
        rm "${dir}/Library/Preferences/com.apple.eap.bindings.*"
    fi
done
```

Above code does not delete the file in question but it does work if I point to the exact file name without the wildcard.
I have tried removing quotes as well but still does not delete the file. Could someone help please?

Comment: rm isn't your problem; wildcard matching in [[ -e ]] is.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-wildcard-in-shell-script

Answer (score 2):

```
if [[ -e "${dir}/Library/Preferences/com.apple.eap.bindings.*" ]]; then
```

In this line you put the asterisk within double quotes.  That makes it a literal char and not something which magically expands to filename(s).

Links: [double-quotes-vs-asterisk-filename-expansion-in-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455780/double-quotes-vs-asterisk-filename-expansion-in-bash) as well as [the post already pointed to by Shaun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-wildcard-in-shell-script).

You will have to use the asterisk unquoted. Either as in the first part of your script or as an argument to [`find`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html).

Comment: Removing the quotes will fail if the asterisk matches more than one file. Better to use `if [ -z "$(echo ${dir}/Library/Preferences/com.apple.eap.bindings.*|grep -q '*')" ]; then`

Comment: Thank you Thank you AFH! That works perfecto! This thing was starting to eat my brains out.  Now thats what I call a perfectly helpful & understanding forum answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You could consider this as an alternative

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/find /Users/*/Library/Preferences -name "com.apple.eap.bindings.*.plist" -exec /bin/rm -fv "{}" \;
```

This will effectively remove the files in question. Remove the 'v' switch if you don't want output.

Answer (score 1):

If this should help anyone out there, this is what works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in /Users/*;
do
    if [ -z "$(echo ${dir}/Library/Preferences/com.apple.eap.bindings.*|grep -q '*')" ]; then
        rm ${dir}/Library/Preferences/com.apple.eap.bindings.*
    fi
done
```