# Not finding folders in bash script with use of asterix

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to delete several subfolders from the terminal on Mac (running on bash). The subfolders are starting on the same two letters "na", and I have made a code like this:

```
       if [[ -d "$base/${subject}/${session}/"na* ]]; then
echo "removing na folder from all folders"
rm -rf "$base/${subject}/${session}/"na*
```

I have tried a variety of different ways to write it up (with * inside and outside brackets, na inside and outside brackets and more). When I run the code it does not echo the message, so it is not finding the folders. After reading the answer on a similar question ([remove rm command not working with wildcards on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/832933/remove-rm-command-not-working-with-wildcards-on-mac-os-x)) I made a "while-loop" to make sure it does not stop after one folder, but the problem still remains that the "na*" folders are not found in the first place. If I substitute the * with an exact subfolder-name, it works. But that is rather inconvenient.

Hope anyone can help!

---

Edit:

Thank you both for the replies.
The bit of code from Maciorowski did the trick and solved the problem! Also big thanks for an educational answer. Did not know of the caveat of [[ and *.

Comment: Actually, unless there are too many `na*` folders (see one of the answers below) `rm -rf "$base/${subject}/${session}/"na*` will do most of time, without any prior test. Thanks to the `-f`option `rm` will not complain even if the list is empty (no `na*` folder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The words between the `[[` and `]]` do not undergo […] filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html). Your first `*` is not expanded. Apparently there is no subdirectory named (literally) `na*`, the test fails and thus `rm` is not performed.

If `rm` was going to be performed, `*` there would be expanded first.

The diagnosis in [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1745736/432690) that "[the first] `na*` will expand to several names" is wrong. `na*` there does not expand at all.

If you used `[ -d …/na* ]` instead of `[[ -d …/na* ]]` then `na*` would be expanded and *then* you might get several pathnames (`[` would print an error). [`[` and `[[` are not equivalent](https://superuser.com/a/1708896/432690).

`rm -rf "$base/${subject}/${session}/"na*` is somewhat flawed. As `rm` is not a builtin in Bash, the line after expansion may be too long and you may get [`Argument list too long`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647755/10765659). The link leads to an answer with two different solutions: with `for` and with `find`. An example of the `for` solution tailored to your case may be:

```
( shopt -s nullglob
mark=
for d in "$base/$subject/$session/"na*/; do
  [ -z "$mark" ] && { mark=1; echo "Removing \`na*' directories from \`$base/$subject/$session/'" >&2; }
  echo rm -rf "$d"
done )
```

(Fail-safe, dry run. Replace `echo rm` with `rm` if the result looks good.)

Notes:

- The trailing backslash in `na*/` causes the pattern to match directories only.
- `shopt -s nullglob` is in case `na*/` matches zero directiories. Normally the pattern with zero matches would stay literal; with `nullglob` it expands to zero words, our loop becomes `for d in; do …` and its body is executed zero times.
- Your original message (`removing na folder from all folders`) is misleading. Neither my code nor your original code tries to "remove folder from folders". `$base/$subject/$session/` cannot be "folder**s**". I changed the message.
- I manipulate `mark` to echo the message only when it's needed and only once. It seems this is what you want.
- To me the message looks "diagnostic", hence `>&2`.
- The snippet is run in a subshell. The point is `nullglob`, `mark` and `d` are local to the shubshell and cannot affect anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting `na*` will expand to several names, but as far as I know the `-d` test accepts a single argument. Moreover, as pointed out in the other answer no expansion occurs inside `[[ ]]`.

A solution is to iterate with `find`:

`find "$base/${subject}/${session}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "na*" -exec rm -rf {} \;`

And in the case you would like to recursively remove all the "na*" folders in the tree structure starting from base:

`find "$base" -type d -name "na*" -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks for pointing out the errors. Yes `-depth 0` means the strating point only, `-depth 1` is needed here, and yes BSD `find` complains if the trailing `;` is absent ;). I don't get *"I believe the OP may use one or the other on Mac"*: unless he deliberately installed the GNU `find` (via Brew or MacPorts...), there is only the BSD version in macOS.

Comment: (4) "unless he deliberately installed" – We don't know and this is my point. People do install GNU `find` on Mac. (5) "the equivalent option is `-maxdepth n`" – No. AFAIK FreeBSD `find` supports `-maxdepth n` as well. This primary makes `find` descend at most `n` directory levels, no further; it's "global". `-depth n` is a test performed *separately* for every file tested, it does not prevent further descent. With `-depth n` you can do different tests/actions to files at depth 1, different at depth 2 and so on. With `-maxdepth 1` you never get to depth 2.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski OK I am always confused between `-depth` and `-maxdepth` and didn't check this time (that said I think that `-depth 1` or `-maxdepth 1`would result in the same actions in the command here (this would not be true with `-depth 2` vs `-maxdepth 2`)... Frankly, the number of Mac users who use the bash command is quite low, and the ones who install additional command line tools are even less numerous... And the latter ones are generally aware that there exist some differences between the GNU and BSD utilities.

Comment: About `-depth 1` vs `-maxdepth 1`: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38600497). (6) With `-maxdepth 1` and *without* `-depth 1` (or `-mindepth 1`) `$base/${subject}/${session}` is tested as the first file and *if* it passes `-type d -name "na*"` then `rm -rf` will remove the entire directory. Judging by the OP's code, I say this is *not* what they want, ever. The mishap will or will not happen, depending on what string `$session` expands to; and we don't know this. I know I'm nagging, but `rm -rf` is destructive. My code hopefully is not flawed, yet I used `echo rm …` just in case.

Comment: So after all `-depth 1` would have do... It's also the responsibility of the user to test/understand the scripts found on the internet (here or anywhere else) and not just copy/paste/running them directly on important data. Even for my own scripts I am first either replacing the commands that can change the data (`rm` or whatever else) by echos, or running them on test/duplicated data.

Comment: (7) "`-depth 1` would have do…" – Yes, and I did not say it was wrong. I said it's not equivalent to `-maxdepth 1`. Replacing `-depth 1` with `-maxdepth 1` was your (somewhat unfortunate) decision. (8) "It's also the responsibility of the user to test" – True, but we have downvotes to indicate bad (e.g. flawed) answers and you probably don't want your answers to be downvoted. IMO the first version of your answer was bad, yet fixable. I deliberately did not mention `find` in my answer, thinking it's better to fix yours. And here we are; after all the struggle you have an upvote from me.